# Copy a file from SharePoint and open it on the user's c drive

Tags: microsoft-access

I would like to copy a Microsoft Access .mde file from a document library to a c drive folder on the user's computer and open it there. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the Edit Control Block (or the drop-down menu) for the item and go to **Send To** -> **Download a Copy** and save it on the user's computer.

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as an answer. That's the best way to thank a poster for their answer :)